# SSRS Multi Value Parameter - Deselect a parameter on selecting another parameter

Tags: reporting-services

Is it possible to deselect a certain parameter in SSRS multi value parameter report when a different parameter is selected?

[image: Multi Value Parameter example]

Consider the above image as an example. I want this work in such a way that, when I select **DEFAULT** parameter, all the other parameters should be unchecked whether it was already unchecked or not.
Same way, when any other parameter (**VAL1, VAL2, VAL3**) is checked, **DEFAULT** should be unchecked.
I just know 1 way which includes a complicated set of code in each of the parameter values.
Is there a simpler way to achieve this? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the DEFAULT value represent all the other values? It seem like you want this to behave just like the "SELECT ALL" option.

Comment: so whats the difference between Default and Select All?